# Laravel: Undefined variable content

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have setup a `Route`:

```
Route::resource('conferences', 'ConferencesController)
```

`Artisan` therefore shows me a route:

`POST conferences | conferences.store | ConferencesController@store`

When I submit a `Form` from the `create` View, I get the error that a variable in my layout file has not been defined.
`Undefined variable: content` is shown, nothing has been posted.

I opened my form like this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/conferences', 'class' => 'conference-form')) }}
```

And finally, my `store` method in `ConferencesController` looks like this:

```
public function store()
{
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Conference::$rules);

    if($validator->passes()){
        $conference = new Conference();
        $conference->title = Input::get('title');
        $conference->description = Input::get('description');
        $conference->location = Input::get('location');
        $conference->plannedTime = Input::get('plannedTime');
        $conference->save();

        Mail::pretend();
        Mail::send('emails.conference.create', ['title' => Input::get('title'), 'location' => Input::get('location'), 'plannedTime' => Input::get('plannedTime')], function($message){
            $message->to('email')->subject('Een nieuw evenement is gemaakt.');
        });

        Redirect::to('/conferences')->with('message', 'Nieuw event is aangemaakt!');
    } else {
        Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'Iets ging mis');
    }
}
```

How do I fix this error?

** EDIT: Added create method **

```
public function create(){
    $this->layout->content = View::make('conferences.create');
}
```

Comment: Can you show us you create method please?

Comment: Added create method for you :)

Comment: try just
    public function create(){
       return View::make('conferences.create');
    }

Comment: Edit: it loads the view now, but not within the layout file, just on its own?

Comment: in your views folder you need to have a folder called conferences with a create.blade.php in there

Comment: That folder and file are present, because Laravel does load the form when I visit /conferences/create.
Laravel loads the view, only thing is that it doesn't pass it to my layouts.main file anymore and that POST still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This should be really straight forward. In your views directory we usually have a folder called layouts where we put the page structure something like:

```
// default.blade.php
<html>
 <head> </head>
 <body>
   @yield('content'); // this is where your views will be loaded
 </body>
</html>
```

then in your case you should create a conferences folder and then a file create.blade.php in it.

```
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('content')
  // your forms etc
@stop
```

And in your create method inside ConferencesController

```
public function create() {
 return View::make('conferences.create');
}
```

And one last thing, when you try to send the email you should be passing an email address inside the `to()` function and you are passing a string